# SQL Server Delete Trigger not updating Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm still learning SQL and I'm having issues with a trigger.

I have the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteYTDSales
ON dbo.Sales
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MasterTable
    SET MasterTable.SalesYTD = MasterTable.SalesYTD - Deleted.Amount
    FROM Sales
    JOIN Deleted ON Sales.CustomerID = Deleted.CustomerID 
END
GO
```

After I delete a row from the sales table, I need to update the `SalesYTD` column for the `CustomerID` in the `MasterTable`. Right now it doesn't update the column and I can't figure out why not.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added sql server tag based on `syntax` and infamous `GO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are missing join condition for `MasterTable`. You are looking for this

```
UPDATE m
    SET m.SalesYTD = m.SalesYTD - d.Amount
    FROM MasterTable m
    JOIN Deleted d ON d.CustomerID = m.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update is really weird.  I think you simply intend:

```
UPDATE mt
  SET SalesYTD = mt.SalesYTD - d.Amount
  FROM MasterTable mt JOIN
       Deleted d
       ON mt.CustomerID = d.CustomerID ;
```

In your code, you are updating *all* rows of `MasterTable`.  SQL Server can be a bit tricky with `UPDATE`s.  My advice is to use a `FROM` clause and always put the alias in the `UPDATE`.

You do not need to refer to the `Sales` table, because all the information you need is in `deleted`.

You can also write this as:

```
UPDATE MasterTable
  SET SalesYTD = mt.SalesYTD - d.Amount
  FROM Deleted d
  WHERE MasterTable.CustomerID = d.CustomerID ;
```